# Use a Raspberry Pi 400 to emulate keystrokes on a Mac, based on video input

Tags: keyboard, emulation

I am looking to do an ambitious project using RP 400. I want to be able to “press” left and right key on my Mac based on a video input. For example press left everytime a light is red and right if it is blue. I can train and implement the classification module, but my problem is with the keystroke part. Is there a way that I can send keystrokes to my Mac which is in the same network? I do not want to get into making it a mechanical device which literally presses the keys using two motors.

Ideas?